# C# unity how to use dot product to keep 2 outside vectors relative to a inside vector as inside vector changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`DirSteerTo = DirSteerIndicator.normalized;

```
        DirSteerTo =  DirSteerTo * -1;
        Debug.Log("release");
        //a           DirSteerIndicator is C
        RudderTop = (DirSteerIndicator - RudderBottom).normalized;
        // b          DirSteerIndicator is C
        RudderBottom = (DirSteerIndicator - RudderBottom).normalized;
```

`
[image]

[image]

Comment: why not get your vector rotation and apply to the others vectors this rotation?

Comment: Could you expand your description a bit .. what is the image supposed to show exactly? What is `DirSteerIndicator`, `RudderBottom`, `RudderTop` ... ? And why not just calculate the delta angle to the previous directions and apply the same delta angle rotation to all vectors?

Comment: so vector C(dirSteerIndicator) will change, and i want to update A(rudderTop) and B(rudderBottom) relative to where C changes

Comment: Set the whole system with empty child game objects and you get the vectors without calculation. The system will rotate and place children accordingly.